# Custom Administrator profile

Tags: user, user-management, user-admin

I want to add a user with a custom administrator profile, but who cannot delete the current system administrator users. I tried cloning the System Administrator profile but I can't disable managing intern users. Is there a way I can manage it?

If not, is there a way I can clone the application?

Comment: You probably have the "Manage Users" permission enabled, which implies “Manage Internal Users”. Try turning that permission off first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the **Manage Users** permission enabled, which implies “Manage Internal Users”. Turning that permission off first will allow you to uncheck “Manage Internal Users” as well.